# Listar datas Agendamentos em linha em Uma Tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tom com um Problema aqui que não sei como resolver.
Fiz Uma Agenda que me retorna os usuarios e os chamados que ele teria na semana, isso apresentado em uma tabela igual a uma calendário semanal. vou colocar uma imagens para entender melhor como é hoje e oque eu quero mudar.
[image: Queria todas as datas deste Usuario na mesma linha linha]
Queria  todos os agendamentos deste Usuario na mesma linha e na casa do dias correro

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-white">
<thead>
<tr>
<th >Usuario</th>
<th >Segunda</th>
<th >Terça</th>
<th >Quarta</th>
<th >Quinta</th>
<th >Sexta</th>
<th >Sabado</th>
<th >Domingo</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?

$sql ="SELECT * FROM os where status2 <> 'Fechado' AND start1      
BETWEEN '$dataRecebida' AND '$proximaData' ";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
$id1 = $linha["id1"];              
$nome = $linha["nome_cliente"];
$nome_tec = $linha["nome_tec"];
$tecnico = $linha["nome_tecnico1"];
$start1 = $linha["start1"];

$d1 = substr($start1, 0, 10 );
$t = '&nbsp;';
$d2 = substr($start1, 11, 5 );
$start = $d1.$d2;
$data1 = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$d1)));
$datal = $data1.$t.$d2;

$dia = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start1);
$dia = $dia->format('D');


if($dia === 'Mon'){
$data2 = "<span class='label label-danger'>$id1</span> $datal<br>
</strong>$nome</strong> ";
}else{
$data2 = "";    
} 

if ($dia === 'Tue'){
$data3 = "<span class='label label-danger'>$id1</span> $datal<br>
<strong>$nome</strong> ";
}else{ 
$data3 = "";   
} 
if ($dia === 'Wed'){
$data4 = "<span class='label label-danger'>$id1</span> $datal<br>
<strong>$nome</strong> ";
}else{
$data4 = "";       
} 
if ($dia === 'Thu'){
$data5 = "<span class='label label-danger'>$id1</span> $datal<br>
<strong>$nome</strong> ";
}else{
$data5 = "";           
} 
if($dia === 'Fri'){
$data6 = "<span class='label label-danger'>$id1</span> $datal<br>
<strong>$nome</strong> ";
}else{
$data6 = "";           
} 
if ($dia === 'Sat'){
$data7 = "<span class='label label-danger'>$id1</span> $datal<br>
<strong>$nome</strong> ";
}else{
$data7 = "";          
}         
if ($dia === 'Sum'){
$data1 = "<span class='label label-danger'>$id1</span> $datal<br>
<strong>$nome</strong> ";
}else{
$data1 = "";          
}         
?>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #CEF9FB;" ><?echo $tecnico?></td><td ><?echo $data2?>   
</td><td style="background-color: white;"><?echo $data3?></td><td><?echo $data4?> 
</td>  
<td><?echo $data5?></td><td><?echo $data6?></td><td><?echo $data7?></td><td><?echo   
$data1
?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<?}?>
</table>
```

Alguem saberia como resolver isso

Comment: Fábio, note que na imagem que você postou, existem 2 agendamentos no Sábado, neste caso, como deverá ser mostrado? Se fizer tudo em 1 única linha, esses registros terão se estar juntos de algum modo. Como você imaginou isso?

Comment: Ola Thomas eu Imaginei cada agendamento desses entrar na mesma linha um em baixo do outro então na primeira linha no sábado juntaria os Registros mesmo. Att Fabio

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro você teria que entender como ficaria isso dentro da `<table>` , veja:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Usuário</th>
    <th>Segunda</th>
    <th>Terça</th>
    <th>Quarta</th>
    <th>Quinta</th>
    <th>Sexta</th>
    <th>Sábado</th>
    <th>Domingo</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jó Pereira</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>07/01/2015 14:00<br>Cliente 1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>10/01/2015 08:00<br>Cliente 2<br></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jó Pereira</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>10/01/2015 08:15<br>Cliente 3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jó Pereira</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Observe que para cada nova linha é criado um novo `<tr>`

Após isso você precisa realizar a consulta e ordenar ela por data e hora e fazer um laço for (eu usaria um for ) ou while.